# Newtonsoft.json.dll gives error: Could not load type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2'

Tags: json.net

We use the Newtonsoft.json.dll for several ASP.Net projects on different IIS servers.  When deploying it for use on one server, I received an error I hadn't seen before that said

```
Could not load type System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2'"
```

This was an older server using ASP.Net 4.0, and most of our other servers used ASP.Net 4.5, so I suspected it could be a versioning issue, but it wasn't an option to upgrade ASP.Net versions

Answer (score 0):

Since we couldn't upgrade the ASP.Net version on the server, I had to find an older version of Newtonsoft.json.dll to use on that server.  More specifically, Newtonsoft.json.dll version 7.0.1.x did NOT work on our server with ASP.Net 4.0, but version 4.5.7.x did work with ASP.Net 4.0